# OS update not showing up (Macbook Air early 2015, 10.13.6)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update

I've just tried to install Adobe Bridge on my wife's Air, and got the message that I need a newer macOS for it. Having checked the OS version, I noticed it hasn't been updated since 10.13.6, which is a year old now.

App Store Updates only shows several Apple apps and that are incompatible, presumably because they are all version 11+.

Why doesn't the newer MacOS show up on this computer?

[image: About this Mac]
[image: Software Update]

Comment: It would have nagged for the first year - Mojave was released in 2018 - but would have given up after that. I'm not sure it would be wise to jump all that way in one go, & I certainly wouldn't start without a known-good backup. I think perhaps Catalina would be the 'stepping stone' to use, though some firmware updates were set at Mojave to pave the way. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/85275 for some background & links. Apple did away with the old style App Store at Mojave & OS updates are no longer in that app, they have their own preference pane instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683, Big Sur can update High Sierra and even older versions. Is there any reliable information on why not to make a big jump? I checked the linked answer, and it seems to be partly outdated but importantly doesn't really provide any reliable links, just mentions "received wisdom", which seems to contradict the official information.

Comment: Apple may have changed the installers over the years. "Received wisdom" springs from the number of reports on this site over the years of people trying & failing to do large OS jumps in one go. Note the answer was first written in 2017 & has been in a state of flux ever since. If you have solid backups, feel free to experiment.